# AcriveRecord relationship validation between two or more belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to validate multiple relationships in rails. I don't mean validating an association, rather ensuring relationship integrity between two or more belongs_to associations. Here is some code as an example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :purchases, inverse_of: :user
end

class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :purchases
  has_many :products, inverse_of: :purchase
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :products
  belongs_to :purchase, inverse_of: :products

  validates :user, :purchase, presence: true
  validate :purchase_user

  private

  def purchase_user
    errors.add(:purchase, 'purchase user does not match user') if user != purchase.user
  end
end
```

The `purchase_user` validation method here checks that the `user` is the same as `purchase.user` and adds an error if they are not.

I could change it to use `:inclusion` like so:

```
validates :purchase, inclusion: { in: proc { |record| record.user.purchases } }
```

But that seems even more inefficient, any suggestions?

Comment: You talk about cleaner and inefficient. It is not clear what you mean. Does your code work? What is it that you think need to be improved?

Comment: @Meier Rails has a lot of convenient methods, most of the time there is already some method that does exactly what you want without you having to build it yourself. I feel this is something that should exist. Yes my code works, but I would ideally like to use pre-existing convention rather than write and test it myself.